# [next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms'

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, next-auth

## Describe the issue

I'm using NextAuth and provider is congnito in my application.

This is the error I got

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error outgoing request timed out after 3500ms {
  error: {
    message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms',
    stack: 'RPError: outgoing request timed out after 3500ms\n' +
      '    at C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\openid-client\\lib\\helpers\\request.js:137:13\n' +
      '    at async Issuer.discover (C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\openid-client\\lib\\issuer.js:144:24)\n' +
      '    at async openidClient (C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\lib\\oauth\\client.js:16:14)\n' +
      '    at async getAuthorizationUrl (C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\lib\\oauth\\authorization-url.js:70:18)\n' +
      '    at async Object.signin (C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\routes\\signin.js:38:24)\n' +
      '    at async AuthHandler (C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\index.js:260:26)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthApiHandler (C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\next-auth\\next\\index.js:22:19)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuth._args$ (C:\\Users\\SJ026\\eleck-app\\node_modules\\next-auth\\next\\index.js:106:14)',
    name: 'RPError'
  },
  providerId: 'cognito',
  message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms'
}
```

The front-end UI display Try signing in with a different account. [screenshot](https://imageupload.io/N5QU49flUwW1bWO)

## How to reproduce

In [...nextauth].js:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CognitoProvider from "next-auth/providers/cognito";

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CognitoProvider({
            clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER,
        })
    ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

.env file:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=mL7H6zlYzYwq/p**********iphpEmnXyx6XxIs5I10=

COGNITO_CLIENT_ID=1g8svn6*****sqq7jt9poakiki
COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET=15l3dkjp83o66e1tebsh5iahvauvugc**********9rk2oojs8f0
COGNITO_ISSUER=http://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_*********/
```

## Expected behavior

I expect it can be direct to sign in page like this [screenshot](https://imageupload.io/p9GiEXSEyJzFgJf)

## Environment

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^2.0.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.1",
    "next": "13.4.6",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```